# Permutations: If $3\le m\le n$, Find $\sigma\tau^{-1}$ for the cycles $\sigma=(1\,2\,\ldots,m-1)$ and $\tau=(1\,2\,\ldots,m-1\,m)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

My attempt at the question:

$\tau^{-1} =$ $$m\mapsto m-1\mapsto m-2\mapsto \cdots 2\mapsto 1$$

So starting from

$$1\mapsto 2\mapsto 3\mapsto 4\mapsto \cdots \mapsto m-1\mapsto m$$

Apply $\tau^{-1}$

$$m\mapsto 1\mapsto 2\mapsto 3\mapsto \cdots\mapsto m-2\mapsto m-1$$

Apply $\sigma$

$$m\mapsto 2\mapsto 3\mapsto 4\mapsto \cdots\mapsto m-1\mapsto 1$$

So $\sigma\tau^{-1}= (1,m)(2)(3)\cdots(m-1)$

I'm very new to abstract algebra and am not sure how to incorporate the given fact that $3 \le m\le n$

Comment: I am not sure where $n$ is incorporated. Note if $m<3,$ then you're either doing these shiftings on one or two elements. Exchanging around one element just leaves ... one element in its place, so the symmetric group on one element is just the identity. Exchanging on a set with two elements involves either doing nothing or swapping the two elements, so the symmetric group of order 2 is $\{(1), (1 2)\}$. The theorem actually works if $m=2,$ since $\tau = (1 2)$ (with $\tau^{-1}=(2 1)=(1 2)$) and $\sigma = (1)$ in this case, so $\sigma \tau^{-1} = (1 2) = (1 m).$

Answer (score 1):

Notice $\tau$ just shifts every element to the right once, moving $m$ back over to the first entry. $\sigma$ does the same as $\tau$ except it pretends the $m$th entry isn't there: it rotates all elements to the right once except the $m$th entry, pushing $m-1$ into the first entry.

Applying $\tau^{-1}$ is supposed to get you back where you started if you had applied $\tau$, so that's rotating everything *left* once (putting the first place value in the $m$th place). We then have $$\tau^{-1}(1, 2, \ldots, m) = (2, 3, 4, \ldots, m-1, m, 1)$$ and then have $$\sigma \left(\tau^{-1}(1, 2, \ldots, m)\right) = (m, 2, 3, 4, \ldots, m-2, m-1, 1)$$ which just ultimately swaps the first place with the $m$th place, that is, $$\sigma \tau^{-1}= (1 m).$$

Answer (score 0):

You have done it right.

The algebra here, fortunately, is not abstract. As $\tau$ moves all numbers forward by 1 step (except the last which is sent to 1) $\tau^{-1}$ moves backward by 1 (except . . .).

Now $\sigma$ again moves forward. So $\sigma\circ \tau^{-1}$ should largely restore everything to its place, except the numbers at  the edge. Pay attention to those edges.  So this is not really abstract as it can be described with words, rather than symbols. Here the number $n$ plays no role.

Answer (score 0):

The cycle $\sigma=(1,\,2,\,\ldots,\, m-1)$ can be written as
$$
1 \mapsto 2\mapsto 3 \mapsto \cdots \mapsto (m-1) \mapsto 1 \quad\text{and } \quad m\mapsto m,\ m+1\mapsto m+1,\ \ldots,\ n\mapsto n.
$$
And $\tau = (1,\,2,\,3,\,\ldots,\,m-1,\, m)$ is
$$
1 \mapsto 2\mapsto 3\mapsto \cdots \mapsto (m-1)\mapsto m \mapsto 1 
$$
So $\tau^{-1}$ is
$$
1 \mapsto m \mapsto (m-1) \mapsto (m-2) \mapsto\cdots \mapsto3\mapsto 2\mapsto 1.
$$
Applying $\tau^{-1}$ takes $1$ to $m$ and then applying $\sigma$ takes $m$ to $m$.

Applying $\tau^{-1}$ takes $m$ to $m-1$ and then applying $\sigma$ takes $m-1$ to $1$.

So $1$ and $m$ are interchanged.

Applying $\tau^{-1}$ takes $m-1$ to $m-2$ and then applying $\sigma$ takes $m-2$ to $m-1$.

So $m-1$ is fixed by $\sigma\tau^{-1}$.

Applying $\tau^{-1}$ takes $m-2$ to $m-3$ and then applying $\sigma$ takes $m-3$ to $m-2$.

So $m-2$ is fixed by $\sigma\tau^{-1}$.

Just keep going like that until you understand what $\sigma\tau^{-1}$ does.

Comment: Okay, so $\sigma\tau^{-1}$ brings every element to itself except it takes 1 to m and m to 1 such that $\sigma\tau^{-1}$ = (1,m)(2)(3)(4)... is this the same as writing $\sigma\tau^{-1}$ = (1,m)?

Comment: @Confused : Yes. $\quad\quad$